# Django Rest Framework query data is not json serialiable Error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my views:

```
class BillDetailView(APIView):
    serializer_class = BillSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        bill = Bill.objects.get(flat__id='a flat id')
        return Response(bill)
```

I know to get detailed data, we can use `RetriveAPIView` but I will not use it for some reasons for my business logic.

That is why I am using `APIView`

I am trying to Response the query data as you see but it firing following error:

```
Object of type 'Bill' is not JSON serializable
```

Can anyone help me how to Response the query data?

If I pass a dictionary in `Response` method, It will work great but you it is bad practice for my case.

I just Pass the queried data in Response method. Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Use [DRF Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: I know about serializer but did you see what api class i am using? what is get method? How can i use serialize following my cass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize the **`bill`** object using **`BillSerializer`**

```
#views.py
class BillDetailView(APIView):
    serializer_class = BillSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        bill = Bill.objects.get(flat__id='a flat id')
        return Response(self.serializer_class(bill).data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework import generics

class BillDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
        serializer_class = BillSerializer

        def get_object(self):
            return Bill.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

View should return a Response in `json` format. When you inherit `APIView` you will have to explicitly call the serializer class on the object. 
If you use `generics`, you do not have to worry about that.